# How can I compare the equivalence of keys to values (line 6 of code)

Tags: python

Assume there is a variable , mp_affiliation , that is associated with a dictionary that maps the names of parliament members to party affiliations, associate with the variable  party_size a dictionary that maps party names to the number of members they have.

```
party_size={}
for i in list(mp_affiliation.values):
    party_size[i]=0
for k in mp_affiliation:
    for i in party_size:
        if mp_affiliation[k]==i
            party_size[i]+=1
```

Comment: The comparison is ok, the problem is that you're looping more times than needed: for each member in `mp_affiliation`, you're re-counting the party several times in `party_size`. In other words: you must not nest a loop inside another loop for this problem in particular.

Answer (score 4):

Try this, it's simpler if we use the built-in [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class:

```
from collections import Counter
party_size = Counter(mp_affiliation.values())
```

Now the `party_size` variable will contain a dictionary mapping the political parties with the number of parliament members. But if you want to do this by hand, the long answer would be:

```
party_size = {}
for i in mp_affiliation.values():
    party_size[i]  = 0
for i in mp_affiliation.values():
    party_size[i] += 1
```

Or a bit shorter, using a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict
party_size = defaultdict(int)
for i in mp_affiliation.values():
    party_size[i] += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to import anything special or write methods to do this. Loop through the keys and values, if the political party is already in the dict then add 1 to the member count, else add it to the dict and set member count to 1.

```
party_size = {}
for (k, v) in mp_affiliation.items():
    if v in party_size.keys():
        party_size[v]+=1
    else:
        party_size[v] = 1
```

Comment: its better if you can add some explanation